# Extracting Raster value from sampling point

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have Sample RGB combination from 3 different Bands

[image]

```
// Input RGB imagery
var image = ee.Image("users/k2yulianto/Exercise/Ras/Imagery");

// Use Tree bands from RGB Imagery.
var bands = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
var b1 = ['b1'];
var b2 = ['b2'];
var b3 = ['b3'];

// Display the inputs imagery
Map.addLayer (image, {bands: ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], max: 1, gamma:1, opacity:0.80} , 'RGB imagery',true);
Map.setCenter (101.4476, 0.4925, 12);
```

and have several sampling point on top of the imagery :

```
// Sampling point on top of RGB imagery
var Sampling = ee.FeatureCollection("users/k2yulianto/Exercise/Sampling/Sampling");
Map.addLayer (Sampling, {opacity:0.80},'Sampling point', true);
```

i want to extract raster value in the each bands from imagery using my sampling point
and exported in to shapefile /csv.

the shapefile/csv should be contain column of original bands combination and each band value in it:

> ID | Latitude | Longitude | b1 | b2 | b3

```
// Empty Collection to fill
var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));

var fill = function(img, ini) {

// gets the values for the sampling points in the current image
var getvalue = image.reduceRegions(Sampling, ee.Reducer.first(),30);

};

// Iterates over the image
var newft = image.iterate(fill, ft);

// Export
Export.table.toDrive(newft,
"anyDescription",
"anyFolder",
"anyNameYouWant");
```

When i run my scripts and i got error warning

> "image.iterate is not a function".

How can i solved this problem.

i need to export the value raster to shapefile or csv
that the column will contain :

> ID | Latitude | Longitude | b1 | b2 | b3

here is the link of my original scripts:

> https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e4200dfe8c8b130430f8e4367712ebf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduceRegions` is *already* the operation you need to extract points from an image. No `iterate` or `map` is involved. This will produce a collection ready to export with the band values at each point:

```
var newft = image.reduceRegions(Sampling, ee.Reducer.first(), 30);
```